# RewriteRule not matching?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^url/(.*)$ url.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Why does `http://mydomain.ext/url/http://www.google.com/` not match the first rule, but the second???

Edit: it seems to work when I comment out the last line, but of course i cannot do that. What's going on?

Edit2: If i change it to this it works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^url/(.*)$ url.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Can anyone explain why the previous version didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request is probably getting rewritten twice: `/url/http://…` → `/url.php` → `/index.php`. Exclude that path from the second rule and it should work:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=url.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, as mentioned in my edit adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` before the last line seems to have the same effect, but your solution is shorter.

Comment: @Alfonso: But your solution is more general than mine and will also exclude any other existing files and directories.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the "start of line anchor": "^" that matches URLs starting with "url/".

Try a "`^.*url/(.*)$`", for example.

Comment: Doesn't the request URL start with `url/`? e.g. `http://foo.bar/url/http://www.google.com/`